# Css style sheet partly loading

Tags: php, css, load

My file structure is as follows....

> iamdan > css > style.css

My php file, `head.php` is in a file called `includes` which is in:

> iamdan > includes > head.php

which contains the following code:

```
<head>
<title>Website title!!!</title>
<meta charset="UTF"-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Now it's loading the info fine and some of the style sheet (just the font style) none of the other styling is coming through...

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `<meta charset="UTF"-8">` to `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

Comment: Perhaps `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">` might work. But as you have supplied little info it is hard to tell what else is going wrong.

Comment: @Xenolithic - Thanks for spotting the typo now ammending but that is affecting it.

Comment: @Ed Heal - the strange thing is, if I keep the head section within the main index the style sheet loads fine. When I move the head section into the includes file it still loads the information and part of the style sheet but not the full style sheet, you can see the site iamdanbarrett.com I am editing it live as a test.

Comment: @Dan - Stick the stuff in fiddle. You probably have an error in the style sheet. Check your braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your meta charset:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And the other thing is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

This is relative from your script position. When you are in a subfolder. The path is wrong.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Put a `/` before your path. Then your browser load the css file always from the root:

```
xx.de/css/style.css
```

Or put the complete URL before your script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://xx.xx.de/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: This is so bizarre, I have amended the charset thanks all for spotting that but it isn't making a difference. It is only when I place the head in a sub dir that it will not load the stylesheet...

Comment: Hmm then you have forgotten an `;` in your css file. Then sometimes the rest of the script is not running.

Comment: It isnt even loading the stylesheet at all anymore :S

Comment: Take Firebug and check the script. Perhaps your path is wrong.

Comment: check it out at iamdanbarrett.com you can see for yourself I have literally added the stylesheet directly to the index.php and it is wierd why its not loading, the css is solid I havnt changed it at all.

Comment: The css is loading ;) when you click on your style.css and change something its working. So there is not problem.

Comment: Can you see that its blue or is the page white??

Comment: This is not a loading problem. Perhaps you have to forgotten to clear your divs or something else. But this is not problem regarding your question.

Comment: You where correct, there was ; missing! OMG I feel so ashamed of myself I have been styling for years and it is one of those days...I am learning Php finally and I thought i was doing something wrong...I am so sorry